# django check which users approved document

Tags: django

I have two models

```
class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)

class Approval(models.Model):
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='approval user')
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=APPROVELS, default=1, help_text="Approved")
```

i want to list all document with current login user approval status, when a user approve/Abstain/Not Approved a document i am recording in Approval table otherwise there is no record about current user approval status in Approval table

Please help me with the view and template.

Answer (score 1):

On view:

```
userApprovals = Approval.objects.filter( user = request.user )
or
userApprovals = request.user.approval_user_set.all()
forYourApproval = Document.objects.exclude( pk__in = [ a.document.pk for a in userApprovals ] )
```

and don't forget to include userApprovals on render_to_response:

```
return render_to_response(
                  "yourPage.html", 
                  {
                   "userApprovals": userApprovals,
                   "forYourApproval": forYourApproval,
                   },
                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

On template:

```
{% for approval in userApprovals %}
   {{ approval.document.name }} status {{ approval.get_status_display }}
{% endfor %}

{% for document in forYourApproval %}
   {{ document.name }} waiting for your approval.
{% endfor %}
```

Note: change related name to 'approval_user'.

Comment: there is no approval record for every document in Approval table... Approval table is only updated when a user submit his approval status... otherwise the approval status is 'For your Approval'

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether your requirements allow any user to approve a document, but I'm inferring that this is the case based on your models. If a `Document` can only be approved by a specific user, or set of users, or if a document is approved by multiple users, you will need to make some substantial changes to your model design.

If not, I would write a view like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def approval_view(request):
    documents = Document.objects.filter(
         Q(approval__id__isnull=True) | Q(approval__user=request.user))
    return render_to_response(template_name, {'documents': documents})
```

This will return a context with documents that have no Approval record in the approval table OR who have been approved by `request.user`.

You will likely need some additional code to display the appropriate information for each document in `documents`. For example, a custom template filter that displays a document status (`"For your Approval"` or `"Approved"` or whatever) might be necessary. An example template fragment:

```
{% for document in documents %}
    <li>{{ document.name }} - {{ document|approval_status }}</li> 
{% endfor %}
```

As I said at the beginning, your requirements are not clear. Is every user to be given an opportunity to approve a document? Or do all documents get a single opportunity to be approved by any user? There is a big difference and this code reflects the latter assumption.

If every user is to be given an opportunity to approve a document and you need to display the current user's approval decision, then the above code will work with slight modification. I would probably modify the view to display all documents in some order:

```
documents = Document.objects.all()
```

And then use a custom template filter as above to display the approval status for the current user (passing in the user as an argument):

```
<li>{{ document.name }} - {{ document|approval_status:request.user }}</li>
```